# How can do RESTful based basic authentication in angular2 or angular4?

Tags: angular, forms-authentication, basic-authentication, angular2-forms

I want to login from angular2/angular4 with basic and form-based authentication.

Since my server-side will support only these.

I followed [this link](http://plnkr.co/edit/9luTng?p=preview)

But here they have done using token but I don't use tokens

So I tried the following

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { GeneralService } from './general.service';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: Http, private generalService: GeneralService) {
    var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

}

login(username: string, password: string) {
      let header: Headers = new Headers();
      header.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(username + ":" + password)); 
      header.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/server/authentication/login", {headers: header})
      .map((response:Response) => {
               localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({ username: username }));
                return true;
      })
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}

logout() {
    console.log("logging out");
    return this.http.post("http://localhost:8080/server/authentication/logout", {})
    .map((response:Response) => {
        console.log("logout success");
        localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
     })
      .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
}

}
```

Also **login.html**

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
<h2>Login</h2>
<form name="form" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && login()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !username.valid }">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !username.valid" class="help-block">Username is required</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !password.valid }">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
        <div *ngIf="f.submitted && !password.valid" class="help-block">Password is required</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

I'm facing two issues with this code

1. My server-side not recognized this as a form based request. Since it will support only form-based authentication.  **Is this correct or form based do we need to show login in modal popups?**
2. If I click Logout button on my header. It goes to the exact method "logout()" in the AuthService. Console.log works fine but the logout service not going. Checked the same in developer console "Network" tab.

What is wrong with my approach?

Comment: 1. Because it isn't? You claim to be posting form data, but don't include a body and put the information in the headers.

Comment: **Not related but important**: Don't import the entire `rxjs` library. You are practically avoiding benefits of tree-shaking. For each operator, add by importing `rxsj/add/operators/map` for the `.map` operator, `rxjs/add/operators/switchMap` for `.switchMap` and so on.